# OS X: is there any (area selection) screenshot tool that can upload to Imgur?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

On Windows, I was spoilt by the fantastic [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org), a superb (and free) screenshot tool that had among its many features, uploading to Imgur.com.

I currently use CloudApp but I've reached my 'limit' for uploads and I don't feel like paying for their Pro service when there's myriad of free (and better) image hosting services like Imgur etc.

So are there any screenshot apps which can plug into Imgur?

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of searching in the past for the same thing and didn't really find anything. Although this doesn't upload directly to Imgur, it's not very time consuming.

---

**Step One:**

Take a screenshot of an area with the keyboard shortcut **Command (⌘)-Shift-4**

[image: Example of screen shot with shortcut.]

*End result should be something like this.*

---

**Step Two:**

Just upload it to Imgur. http://imgur.com

[image]

---

[List of other keyboard screenshot shortcuts.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph11229)

Comment: I really am looking for an app that does it in one hotkey, as indicated in the question. I'm currently trying out Captured though, a low-priced app in the Mac App Store. Also Slingshot might do the job but I'm not sure if it can do area selection or not. Captured seems to have a (del-breaking) bug for me right now so I'm very disappointed in it.

Comment: I made the switch to LightShot a while back. Although it doesn't upload to Imgur it does the job for me. It seems like exactly what your looking for except the Imgur part. http://app.prntscr.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one can help:

[mac2imgur](https://github.com/mileswd/mac2imgur) -- A simple Mac application designed to make uploading images and screenshots to imgur.com quick and effortless.

PS: Apparently this project is not currently actively maintained, the last update to the source code has been made 2016. So it may or may not work in more recent versions of macOS and/or with current versions of Swift.

It work for Catalina 10.15.0.